# Programmatically integrate Rubocop formatter with stdin/stdout

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to integrate Rubocop's formatter in an editor: given some Ruby code as an input, return a string representing the equivalent formatted code. I was considering the `-s` option as suggested by Rubocop's help:

> -s FILE - Pipe source from STDIN, using FILE in offense reports. This is useful for editor integration.

In a terminal, the following command successfully reads the input contents and prints the formatted output to stdout:

`cat some_file.rb | rubocop -a -f fi -s some_file.rb`

However, I'm not able to programmatically reproduce something similar using the Rubocop API. I was hoping to somehow feed the input to a `RuboCop::Runner`, however, simply parsing the options hangs before I get to that point:

```
require 'rubocop'

input = "some_var    = 'hello'"
options, paths = RuboCop::Options.new.parse(['-a', '-f', 'fi', '-s', 'some_file.rb'])
runner = RuboCop::Runner.new(options, RuboCop::ConfigStore.new)
...
```

Of course, one option would be to drop `-s` and operate on temporary files, but that adds complexity and is less efficient.

How do I conveniently produce a formatted output using the API?

Comment: can I ask what editor integration you're trying to build integration for and also did you have a guide or instructions on how to do this?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I'm targeting the Solagraph project, therefore any editor that has Language Server Protocol support. I submitted a PR that triggers the formatting using temporary files (https://github.com/castwide/solargraph/pull/239), but I feel it's somewhat slow and clunky, hence this question to try to come up with a better approach.

Comment: Calling [`Options::parse`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/b88c6e26e78056fa0cf9f450c276821d257ff98f/lib/rubocop/options.rb#L38) will try to read from `stdin` so your process gets stuck. Why don't you just call Rubocop using [`popen(3)`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) as another process and write to this processes stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Just call RuboCop as an external process, e.g. using `Open3.capture2`:

```
stdout_str, status = Open3.capture2("rubocop -a -f fi -s some_file.rb", input)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts! This was the initial approach, but was causing various issues. Doing so assumes that the "rubocop" executable is available on the user's path, which is not necessarily the case and assumes that the editor has access to that path, which is not the case for some IDEs which run in their own separate environment. It's also less efficient than plugging into the API directly and has other drawbacks, e.g. error handling.